# How to comprephend these ways could eliminate most need for explicit std::move? Could anybody make it clear by some simple examples?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

How to comprephend these ways(including not making variables’ scopes needlessly large, writing short functions that return values, returning local variables) could eliminate most need for explicit std::move?

Could anybody make it clear by some simple examples?I am a novice in C++.I would be grateful for any hint on this question.
For your convenience, I post all the quotes below.

> Moving is done implicitly when the source is an rvalue (e.g., value in a return treatment or a function result), so don’t
>   pointlessly complicate code in those cases by writing move explicitly.
>   Instead, write short functions that return values, and both the
>   function’s return and the caller’s accepting of the return will be
>   optimized naturally.
>       In general, following the guidelines in this document (including not making variables’ scopes needlessly large, writing short functions
>   that return values, returning local variables) help eliminate most
>   need for explicit std::move.

Comment: Keep in mind that `std::move` is just a type cast and doesn't actually do anything; it just creates the opportunity for "moving" (which doesn't physically move anything) if it didn't already exist.

Comment: Returning by value from a function functionally casts to rvalue. You don't need to write `std::move(my_function())` when `my_function` returns by value. It's the same as `my_function()`. I *think* the advice in the quote is to use these kinds of functions more to reduce the number of `std::move`s. But I'm not sure that is good advice. If you go out of your way to write a function just to produce an rvalue, just use `std::move` instead and make everything clear to future readers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much.The documentation forementioned is very useful indeed.But,i think it could not answer my question because i want to know why the several ways could eliminate most need for explicit `std::move`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating sub-functions, you might change

```
void consume(std::vector<int>&&);

void foo()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    consume(std::move(v));
}
```

by

```
void consume(std::vector<int>&&);

std::vector<int> make_vector()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    return v; // implicit move. or NRVO
}
void foo()
{
    consume(make_vector()); // no explicit move needed.
}
```

which also allow better reading.

Comment: Glad to see you again.Thank you for the clarification.